# aws php refresh token, doesn't have return refresh token

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

I have aws sdk php cognito to refresh token,

```
    public function refreshToken($username, $refreshToken)
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->client->initiateAuth([
                'AuthFlow' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
                'AuthParameters' => [
                    'SECRET_HASH' => $this->cognitoSecretHash($username),
                    'REFRESH_TOKEN' => $refreshToken
                ],
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
            ]);
        } catch (CognitoIdentityProviderException $exception) {
            if ($exception->getAwsErrorCode() === self::NOT_AUTHORIZED) {
                $this->add_error('You are unauthorized to access this resource');
                return false;
            }

            throw $exception;
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

for refresh token return success 200, but for return RefreshToken in AuthenticationResult is missing :

```
[
    'AuthenticationResult' => [
        'AccessToken' => '<string>',
        'ExpiresIn' => <integer>,
        'IdToken' => '<string>',
        'RefreshToken' => '<string>', // return missing RefreshToken
        'TokenType' => '<string>',
    ],
    ...
]
```

why RefreshToken in AuthenticationResult is missing? I can't refresh token again if result from initiateAuth REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH can't provided?

Answer (score 0):

i think userPool id is missing  you can correct like that ;

```
//...
'AuthFlow' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
                    'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                    'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
                    'AuthParameters' => [
// ...
```